# Firefox Plugin or anyother to List shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, paste

Inspired by usage of SE sites, I frequently have to flag Off topic post and write a comment telling OP to make the post on a different SE site. Usually, I go to the bottom of the page to retrieve the link from there. What I find to be useful is, I could click some shortcuts and a list of pre-set values will be shown and I could scroll those using my keyboard and press enter and that same text will be pasted where the shortcut was initiated from

Does such a Plugin exist for Firefox, or any Windows based application that would help me to achieve similar outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to spend a bit of time with [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), or [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows). They're great standard-issue automation tools.